# Как реализовать систему оповещения для кроссплатформенного приложения (notification или push — notification | JS + PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, phonegap, уведомления, push-уведомления

Есть бэкенд на PHP. Есть phonegap - приложение (html+css+js).

Суть в чём, у пользователя есть подписка в приложении.
Нужно присылать ему уведомление за 3 дня(к примеру), что скоро подписка 
аннулируется.

Каким образом получать эти уведомления на телефон с помощью js?
Нужно ли удалять эти оповещения из БД, после того как пользователь их просмотрел?

Есть мысли о setTimeout с интервалом в 5 секунд(к примеру), т.е. вызывать функцию checkNotification каждые 5 секунд, в которой будет ajax - запрос . Но не сильно ли это будет напрягать сервер, когда пользователей будет много?

Подскажите пожалуйста, у кого какие есть соображения по этому поводу. Вообще есть ли готовые решения или какой способ будет оптимальным?

Кстати, у cordova есть плагин с push - notification, но может есть способ просто обойтись js + php?